# Find maximum from a unindexed column of mixed integers and strings in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

`I have a data without column headers and I want to find the max and min latitude and longitude which is index[2] and index[4] followed by index[3]=N and index[5]=E.`

`Example of the data is as follows:`

`1,5,6,9n,8,4,9,0`

`3,66,t,87,5,8`

`2,s,1.23,N,1.39,E`

`1,2,1.45,N,1.26,E,2N,9`

`7,-3,5,L,67,34,K,78,6,4`

I have tried the following:

```
with open ("E:\\abc\xyz.txt", "r") as file1:
        Lines = file1.readlines()
        data = Lines
        for line in Lines:
                spline = line.split(",")
                l1= []
                l1.append(spline[2])
                print(l1)
```

To get a combined list, so that I can get a max(). However not able to figure out.`
The result image is as follows:

`['6']`

`['t']`

`['1.23']`

`['1.45']`

`['5']`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [**Please do not upload images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). You need to post a [mre] within the question itself.

Comment: what is the output you expect for the input?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.
I ultimately found a solution for the question.
I used

```
pd.read_csv
```

and the max() of index[2] & [4]
Thank you once again